# Update rows of Pandas column using previous rows of same column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame with the following columns:

> blocked,   rolling_mean,   cumulative_i

I max trying to create a new column where:

*c_(i) = max(0, blocked_i - (rolling_mean_i + k) + c_(i-1)) -- where k = 2*

My current approach is:

```
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        if i > 1:
            df.ix[i, 'cumulative_i'] = max(0, df['blocked'].iloc[i] -(df['rolling_mean'].iloc[i] + k) + df['cumulative_i'].iloc[i - 1])
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

**Edit:**

I tried doing the following.

```
    df['cumulative_i'] = np.maximum(0, df['blocked'] - (df['rolling_mean'] + k) + df['cumulative_i'].shift())
```

[image: Sample vectorised output and expected output]

On the third row under vectorised_output. The value 153.48 is what one would get if we don't add the previous value 213.72 (i.e. 367.2 - 213.72 = 153.48).

This is the output I would expect if I were only doing

```
df['cumulative_i'] = np.maximum(0, df['blocked'] - (df['rolling_mean'] + k))
```

Comment: Your code and the formula don't seem to match the formula shows no subtraction but your code does, is this a typo?

Comment: That was a typo. I updated the formula.